# How to use mat-accordion without mat-panel-description

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to use the [mat-accordion](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview) library but without the `mat-panel-description`.

Does it exists a proper way of doing it.

I red through the documentation, but couldn't find any solution.

I know I could hide it with some css, but I would like not to remove my encapsulation for such a small things.

Did I missed something ?

#### Code example

*Even if I do that, it will mat-panel-description will still exists in the DOM*

```html
  <mat-accordion multi>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let i of attributes?.list">
      <mat-expansion-panel class="mat-elevation-z0">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title>
            <h4>{{ i.title }}</h4>
          </mat-panel-title>
          <!-- <mat-panel-description class="hidden"></mat-panel-description> -> I'm actually hiding it with css  --> 
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <div class="panel-container">
          <div class="wysiwyg-container" [innerHtml]="i.content | safe: 'html'"></div>
        </div>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-accordion>
```

### Why ?

I'm loosing a lot of free space on smaller device.

[image]

Comment: Just don't put the description ... ?

Comment: @MGX Sorry, I've updated my question. I do not have the description set, but angular-material is still adding it

Comment: Why do you want to remove it to being with ?

Comment: @MGX I've updated my question to add more context

Comment: So you want to stick the opening arrow to your text ?

Comment: @MGX The arrow stay at the right, but the title will have more space.

Answer (score 0):

In your `style.scss` file, NOT in your component file, add this

```css
mat-panel-description {
  flex: 0 0 0% !important;
}
```

This should force the description to take up no space at all.

Comment: I'm not sure if placing css globaly in my project is better than removing the encapsulation of my component. 

I have more change to influence something other accordion where I may have wanted the description to be shown

Comment: Then use a custom css selector, like `mat-panel-description[dense]`